How to use VitePress without Single-File Components
I'm working on a Vue.js project with Vite and wanna have a automatic documentation with vitePress. When I try to build the docs I get the error that at least one of the tags have to be inside of my components (, ). But I'm not creating my components as Single-File Components. I split them into 3 files (index.ts, template.tpl and style.scss) How can I customize the config file to solve that issue ?
Error shows up after run: npm run docs:dev

I think Vitepress is then not a good choice in this situation. Maybe give a try to Starlight or any other one. Auto-documentation is not something that popular and the most common usage of Vue components is still SFC, so you will not have an easy-to-use defaults if you do your own sauce.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
